# Убрать расширение .php в nginx

Tags: php, nginx, ссылки

Привет всем! Частая проблема, прочитал много по этому поводу но так нифига и не понял.

У меня все ссылки на сайте следующего типа: `contactinf` вместо `contactinf.php` и так для всех файлов и файлов в субдиректориях. Достигнуто с помощью PHP + .htaccess кода:

PHP:

```
if(stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php")){
   $currentPage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
   $shortCut = str_replace(".php", "", $currentPage);
   header("Location:".$shortCut);
}
```

.htaccess:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

В nginx такое не работает, и все мои ссылки перестали работать из-за того, что я не указал `.php` в конце ссылки. Если надо, то прикреплю полный конфиг `nginx.conf` файла:

```html
#load_module "modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so";
#load_module "modules/ngx_http_perl_module.so";
#load_module "modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so";
#load_module "modules/ngx_mail_module.so";
#load_module "modules/ngx_stream_module.so";

user                         root admin;
worker_processes             4;

events {
    worker_connections       27000;
}

http {
    include             mime.types;
    default_type             text/html;
 charset                  utf-8;
 error_page 500           http://localhost/errors/undefined;
    error_page 404           http://localhost/errors/undefined;
    error_page 403           http://localhost/errors/undefined;
 gzip                     on;
 gzip_types               text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon image/png image/jpeg;
    
    sendfile                 on;

 server {
  listen               80 default_server;

  # MAMP DOCUMENT_ROOT !! Don't remove this line !!
  root                 "/Users/eugen/Documents/HTML,CSS,PHP, JavaScript,XML lessons/ER website/en/";

  access_log           /Applications/MAMP/logs/nginx_access.log;
  error_log            /Applications/MAMP/logs/nginx_error.log;

  location / {
               index index.html index.htm index.php; 
  }
   
     
  location ~* /MAMP[^-]*(.*)$ {
   root             /Applications/MAMP/bin;
   index            index.php;

   location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files        $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI.sock;
    fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include          fastcgi_params;
   }
  }

  location ~* /phpMyAdmin(.*)$ {
   root             /Applications/MAMP/bin;
   index            index.php;

   location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files        $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI.sock;
    fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include          fastcgi_params;
   }
  }

  location ~* /phpPgAdmin(.*)$ {
   root             /Applications/MAMP/bin;
   index            index.php;

   location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files        $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI.sock;
    fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include          fastcgi_params;
   }
  }
  
  location ~* /phpLiteAdmin(.*)$ {
   root             /Applications/MAMP/bin;
   index            index.php;

   location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files        $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI.sock;
    fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include          fastcgi_params;
   }
  }
  
  location ~* /SQLiteManager(.*)$ {
   root             /Applications/MAMP/bin;
   index            index.php;

   location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files        $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI.sock;
    fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include          fastcgi_params;
   }
  }

  location ~* /adminer(.*)$ {
   root             /Applications/MAMP/bin;
   index            adminer.php;

   location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files        $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI.sock;
    fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include          fastcgi_params;
   }
  }
  
      location ~ .(ini|phps|log|txt|rtf)$ {
              deny all;
              allow 192.168.0.101;
              allow 192.168.0.100;
              allow 192.168.0.102;
              allow 93.75.31.82;
              allow 127.0.0.1;
         }
  
  location /icons {
   alias /Applications/MAMP/Library/icons;
   autoindex on;
  }
  
  location /favicon.ico {
   alias /Applications/MAMP/bin/favicon.ico;
            # log_not_found off;
            # access_log off;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
   try_files        $uri =404;
   fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI.sock;
   fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   include          fastcgi_params;
  }

  location ~ /\. {
   deny all;
  }

  # location ~* \.(gif|jpg|png|pdf)$ {
        # expires          30d;
  # }

     # location = /robots.txt {
        # allow all;
        # log_not_found off;
        # access_log off;
     # }

     # location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
        # allow 127.0.0.1;
        # deny all;
     # }
     
     # location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
        #               return 403;
     # }

  location /nginx_status {
   stub_status      on;
   access_log       off;
   allow            127.0.0.1;
   deny    all;
  }
 }

    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

 #  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}
}

http {
    include             mime.types;
    default_type             text/html;
 charset                  utf-8;
 error_page 500           http://localhost/errors/undefined;
    error_page 404           http://localhost/errors/undefined;
    error_page 403           http://localhost/errors/undefined;
 gzip                     on;
 gzip_types               text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon image/png image/jpeg;
    
    sendfile                 on;

 server {
  listen               80 default_server;

  # MAMP DOCUMENT_ROOT !! Don't remove this line !!
  root                 "/Users/eugen/Documents/HTML,CSS,PHP, JavaScript,XML lessons/ER website/en/";

  access_log           /Applications/MAMP/logs/nginx_access.log;
  error_log            /Applications/MAMP/logs/nginx_error.log;

  location / {
               index index.html index.htm index.php;


             #Deny access for commom bad bots spiders and robots
   
   if (!-e $request_filename){
                return 403;}
   if ($query_string ~ "GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})"){
                 return 403;}
            if ($query_string ~ "FILES(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})"){
              return 403;}
            if ($query_string ~ "_REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^BlackWidow"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^ChinaClaw"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Custo"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^DISCo"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Download\ Demon"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^eCatch"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^EirGrabber"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^EmailSiphon"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^EmailWolf"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Express\ WebPictures"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^ExtractorPro"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^EyeNetIE"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^FlashGet"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^GetRight"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^GetWeb!"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Go!Zilla"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Go-Ahead-Got-It"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^GrabNet"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Grafula"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^HMView"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "HTTrack"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Image\ Stripper"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Image\ Sucker"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "Indy\ Library"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^InterGET"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Internet\ Ninja"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^JetCar"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^JOC\ Web\ Spider"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^larbin"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^LeechFTP"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Mass\ Downloader"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^MIDown\ tool"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Mister\ PiX"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Navroad"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^NearSite"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^NetAnts"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^NetSpider"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Net\ Vampire"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^NetZIP"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Octopus"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Offline\ Explorer"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Offline\ Navigator"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^PageGrabber"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Papa\ Foto"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^pavuk"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^pcBrowser"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^RealDownload"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^ReGet"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^SiteSnagger"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^SmartDownload"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^SuperBot"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^SuperHTTP"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Surfbot"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^tAkeOut"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Teleport\ Pro"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^VoidEYE"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Web\ Image\ Collector"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Web\ Sucker"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WebAuto"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WebCopier"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WebFetch"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WebGo\ IS"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WebLeacher"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WebReaper"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WebSauger"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Website\ eXtractor"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Website\ Quester"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WebStripper"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WebWhacker"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WebZIP"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Wget"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Widow"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^WWWOFFLE"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Xaldon\ WebSpider"){
              return 403;}
   if ($http_user_agent ~* "^Zeus"){
              return 403;}  
     
   rewrite ^(/.*)\.php(\?.*)?$ $1$2 permanent;
            rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
            try_files $uri/index.php $uri.php $uri/ $uri =404;  
  }
 
  location ~* /MAMP[^-]*(.*)$ {
   root             /Applications/MAMP/bin;
   index            index.php;

   location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files        $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI.sock;
    fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include          fastcgi_params;
   }
  }

  location ~* /phpMyAdmin(.*)$ {
   root             /Applications/MAMP/bin;
   index            index.php;

   location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files        $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI.sock;
    fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include          fastcgi_params;
   }
  }

  location ~* /phpPgAdmin(.*)$ {
   root             /Applications/MAMP/bin;
   index            index.php;

   location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files        $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI.sock;
    fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include          fastcgi_params;
   }
  }
  
  location ~* /phpLiteAdmin(.*)$ {
   root             /Applications/MAMP/bin;
   index            index.php;

   location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files        $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI.sock;
    fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include          fastcgi_params;
   }
  }
  
  location ~* /SQLiteManager(.*)$ {
   root             /Applications/MAMP/bin;
   index            index.php;

   location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files        $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI.sock;
    fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include          fastcgi_params;
   }
  }

  location ~* /adminer(.*)$ {
   root             /Applications/MAMP/bin;
   index            adminer.php;

   location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files        $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI.sock;
    fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include          fastcgi_params;
   }
  }
  
      location ~ .(ini|phps|log|txt|rtf)$ {
              deny all;
              allow 192.168.0.101;
              allow 192.168.0.100;
              allow 192.168.0.102;
              allow 93.75.31.82;
              allow 127.0.0.1;
         }
  
  location /icons {
   alias /Applications/MAMP/Library/icons;
   autoindex on;
  }
  
  location /favicon.ico {
   alias /Applications/MAMP/bin/favicon.ico;
            # log_not_found off;
            # access_log off;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
   try_files        $uri =404;
   fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI.sock;
   fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   include          fastcgi_params;
  }

  location ~ /\. {
   deny all;
  }

  # location ~* \.(gif|jpg|png|pdf)$ {
        # expires          30d;
  # }

     # location = /robots.txt {
        # allow all;
        # log_not_found off;
        # access_log off;
     # }

     # location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
        # allow 127.0.0.1;
        # deny all;
     # }
     
     # location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
        #               return 403;
     # }

  location /nginx_status {
   stub_status      on;
   access_log       off;
   allow            127.0.0.1;
   deny    all;
  }
 }

    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

 #  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}
}
```

Comment: Ок, начну конкурс тогда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мдаа.. Ответ оказался таким:

```
location / {
               index index.html index.htm index.php; 
               try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files        $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI.sock;
            fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include          fastcgi_params;
        }

        location @rewrite {
               rewrite ^ $uri.php last;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

в ngix убераем всё лишние и пишем try files секцию

```
 location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /rout.php$is_args$args;
 }
```

в rout.php пишем:

```
if(stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php")){
   $currentPage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
   $shortCut = str_replace(".php", "", $currentPage);
   echo include($shortCut);
}
```

но это писец какой кастыль, и лучше всем ссылкам дописать php

Comment: Не работает, просто пустую страницу выводит, но ошибку не выдает.

Comment: Это не костыль. В ссылках не нужно указывать тип данных.  про семантический URL слышали?